# camera2 API settings are not adopted

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm doing some experiments on the camera2basic sample, by adding a fixed value for the SENSOR_SENSITIVITY of 3000:

```java
private void captureStillPicture() {
        try {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 3000);

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                    Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The camera supports a value between 50 and 3200. Why this value was not adopted for the captured image? If I take a look into the EXIF data the sensitivity is set to 150. Also other sttings are not working. Did I miss some enabled automatic settings inside the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to set the AE mode for the `CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder` from
`requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);`
to
`requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);`
I missed that...